# How can I change what version of Python pyinstaller uses?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

I've come across a really old program that would have great utility to me; however, it didn't come in an executable format. Rather it came in a .py format instead. My problem is that the file was written in Python 2, but every time I try to compile it, pyinstaller uses python 3 instead. I have a version of Python 2 installed on my computer already, with path priority as well. When I type 'python' into PowerShell it outputs the version of Python 2 I have.

How do I set the version of pyinstaller to use Python 2 instead?

Comment: Are you sure you have the pyinstaller package installed in your python2 packages?

Comment: Is there a reason you need it to be a .exe? PyInstaller is usually for distributing Python programs to other computers, which may not have Python (or the correct Python) installed. If you already have Python 2, why not just use that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your path, python3 might be before python2. You might need to temporarily remove python3 from the path, in your windows environment.

   When this is done you may need to use python2's pip to install pyinstaller.
2. Don't use pyinstaller.
   Run in your powershell.

   ```
   python <path_file>\file.py
   ```

   If that works, make a batch file that runs the correct python version by using the full path to the python.exe.